# How to set variable inside of a Coroutine after yielding a webrequest

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, coroutine, yield-return

Okay I will try and explain this to the best of my ability. I have searched and searched all day for a solution to this issue but can't seem to find it.  The problem that I am having is that I have a list of scriptable objects that I am basically using for custom properties to create gameobjects off of.  One of those properties that I need to get is a Texture2D that I turn into a sprite.  Therefor, I am using UnityWebRequest in a Coroutine and am having to yield the response.  After I get the response I am trying to set the variable.  However even using Lambdas it seems to me that if I yield return the response before the result it will not set the variable.  So every time I check the variable after the Coroutine it comes back null.  If someone could enlighten me with what I am missing here that would be just great!

Here is the Scriptable Object Class I am using.

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "new movie",menuName = "movie")]
public class MovieTemplate : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string ImgURL;
    public string mainURL;
    public string secondaryURL;
    public Sprite thumbnail;
}
```

Here is the call to the Coroutine

```c#
foreach (var item in nodes)
{
    templates.Add(GetMovieData(item));
}

foreach (MovieTemplate movie in templates)
{
   StartCoroutine(GetMovieImage(movie.ImgURL, result => 
   {
       movie.thumbnail = result;
   }));
}
```

Here is the Coroutine itself

```c#
IEnumerator GetMovieImage(string url, System.Action<Sprite> result)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest web = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        yield return web.SendWebRequest();
        var img = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(web);
        result(Sprite.Create(img, new Rect(0, 0, img.width, img.height), Vector2.zero));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try it without the `using` .. I might be completely wrong but it might dispose also the local created variables `img` and the created sprite

Comment: @derHugo  Yes I did try it without the using statement with no success.  I did do another test without a webrequest where the yield is below where I set the variable and that works fine when using lambdas.  But the yield return webrequest is what is getting me I think.

Comment: so you have the correct sprite as long as the Coroutine is running? Well the webrequest is essential I guess to get the image ;) and the yield is how you use it so I would not change this for debugging ;) I still think it might be that the `Texture` itself is somehow disposed and therefore your sprite has no texture anymore?

Comment: Have you tried instead return the texture and create the Sprite local in your callback instead?

Comment: @derHugo Yes I have tried to just return the Texture2D and then create the sprite locally but soon as it leaves the Coroutine it becomes null.

Comment: Does the sprite or the texture become `null`?

Comment: regardless of what I try to set anything that I set within the coroutine becomes null.  However if I set a variable before the yield return WebRequest it will hold. But, anything after the yield will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you desribe it still seems that the texture is somehow disposed as soon as the routine finishes. My guess would be that it happens due to the `using` block.

I would store the original texture reference

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "new movie",menuName = "movie")]
public class MovieTemplate : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string ImgURL;
    public string mainURL;
    public string secondaryURL;
    public Sprite thumbnail;
    public Texture texture;

    public void SetSprite(Sprite newSprite, Texture newTexture)
    {
        if(texture) Destroy(texture);

        texture = newTexture;
        var tex = (Texture2D) texture;
        thumbnail = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.zero);
    }
}
```

So you can keep track of the texture itself as well, let it not be collected by the GC but also destroy it when not needed anymore. Usually `Texture2D` is removed by the GC as soon as there is no reference to it anymore but `Texture2D` created by `UnityWebRequest` might behave different.

Than in the webrequest return the texture and don't use `using`

```c#
IEnumerator GetMovieImage(string url, System.Action<Texture> result)
{
    UnityWebRequest web = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url));

    yield return web.SendWebRequest();

    if(!web.error)
    {
        result?.Invoke(DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(web));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Download error: {0} - {1}", web.responseCode, web.error);
    }
}
```

and finally use it like

```c#
for (int i = 0; i < templates.Count; i++)  
{
    int index = i;//If u use i, it will be overriden too so we make a copy of it
    StartCoroutine(
        GetMovieImage(
            templates[index].ImgURL,
            result => 
            {
                templates[index].SetSprite(result);
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because it led me to the right path of thinking and to solve the issue.  I did exactly as you have said and was still getting null on the thumbnail variable.  That got me to thinking about how coroutines work and that I was checking it basically right after the call and so it was executing before the response was given.  The way that I finally got everything to work was to put the additional code in the coroutine as well and that solved the issue.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Timg I hope you kept the `using` block. Otherwise your `UnityWebRequestTexture` object may not get disposed properly and you could end up leaking resources, which could become an issue depending on how often it gets called. The [help page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) isn't very clear on that point.

Comment: Well yes now that we know that the mistake was actually part of a code we couldn't see you should probably go back to what you had already ;)

Comment: Yes I did go back to the using block and just made sure that everything is inside the coroutine and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this section of your code :

```c#
foreach (MovieTemplate movie in templates)
{
   StartCoroutine(GetMovieImage(movie.ImgURL, result => 
   {
       movie.thumbnail = result;//wrong movie obj
   }));
}
```

Here you will loose refrence to movie object(override by foreach) before the result of callback arrive .

Change it to something like this :

```c#
foreach (int i=0;i<templates.Length;i++)  
{
   int index= i;//If u use i, it will be overriden too so we make a copy of it
   StartCoroutine(GetMovieImage(movie.ImgURL, result => 
   {
        templates[index].thumbnail = result;
   }));
}
```

Comment: I have changed the loop to a for loop vs a foreach like so:         for (int i= 0; i < templates.Count; i++)  
        {
            int index = i;
            StartCoroutine(GetMovieImage(((MovieTemplate)templates[index]).ImgURL, result =>
            {
                ((MovieTemplate)templates[index]).thumbnail = result;
            }));
        }

however the variable still comes back as null.